# How to post comment in Linkedin using RestSharp library?

Tags: c#, linkedin-api, restsharp

I'm struggling to add post comment in LinkedIn for the past one week but I didn't get the solution yet

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConsumerKey = "**********";
    string ConsumerSecret = "**********";
    string Token = "**********";
    string TokenSecret = "**********";

    string xmlContent = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + Environment.NewLine +
        "<comment>" + Environment.NewLine +
        "<text>Check out</text>" + Environment.NewLine +
        "</comment>";
    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlContent);

    var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"key1","value1"}
    };
   String requestUrl = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/{post-id}/comments?oauth_token=" + Token;

    RestClient rc = new RestClient();
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(requestUrl, Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "xml");

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
    request.AddBody(xmlContent);

    RestResponse restResponse = (RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
    ResponseStatus responseStatus = restResponse.ResponseStatus;
}
```

I get an error

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
 <error>
     <status>401</status> 
     <timestamp>1375175962003</timestamp> 
     <request-id>10K340J5W6</request-id> 
     <error-code>0</error-code> 
     <message>[unauthorized]. ssl_required</message> 
 </error>
```

I want the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two things wrong.

1. The error says you need to use ssl (ssl_required) so the url should be
   'String requestUrl = "https://api.linkedin...'
   and not 
   'String requestUrl = "http://api.linkedin...'
2. The restSharp.AddBody will encode the object, I believe you need to use

   ```
   request.AddParameter("text/xml", xmlContent, ParameterType.RequestBody);
   ```

   instead of the

   ```
    request.AddBody(xmlContent);
   ```

   line.